# When scrolling fast in UITableView and selecting cell, textfield delegate returns indexPath as nil and crashes

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitextfield, swift3, uitextfielddelegate

I have the structure of my `TableViewController` as such (mentioning for delegation purposes):

```
----View
-----Scroll View
------Content View
-------TableView
--------TableViewCell
```

I can get all of the rows and sections of my `TableView` to load correctly. Each `TableViewCell` has a `UITextField` which is editable. When the user begins to edit the `UITextField`, I need to be able to retrieve the contents of what the user types. To update the correct data sets, the way I am currently doing it is retrieving the `indexPath` of the `UITextField`

My issue is this: When I scroll slowly and click on the `UITextField` one by one, I do not crash. However, if I click on a cell and scroll down quickly (even if I stay in the same `section`), I crash due to the `indexPath` being null.

In my delegate I have this:

```
func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    //here is the code I am using to determine the indexPath
    let view = textField.superview!
    let cell = view.superview as! UITableViewCell
    let viewController = ShowPointsViewController() //this is the name of my ViewController
    let textFieldIndexPath = PointSourcesTV.indexPath(for: cell) //this is the name of my TableView

    print(textFieldIndexPath) //Returns nil here if I scroll too quickly
    let key = tableHeaders[(textFieldIndexPath?.section)!]
}
```

Comment: did you get cell in delegate method ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are using the correct method to get the `indexPath` for the `UITextField` and that may be causing the crash. But you could try something like in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` you can set the tag of the `UITextField` to be the `indexPath.row` and then get the cell instance using-

```
let cell = PointSourcesTV.cellForRowAtIndexPath(IndexPath(row: textField.tag, section: 0)) as! UITableViewCell
```

Comment: Thanks Rikh. This was the approach I originally wanted to take but since I have a variable amount of sections I was not sure how to pass this information into the `textFieldDidEndEditing`. I need information for both the `indexPath.row` and the `indexPath.section` in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` so I can edit my datasets correctly. I see here in the response the `section` is set to 0. Is there another way I can pass this information along variably?

Comment: Well if it were objective - c i could tell you to subclass your `UITextField` and pass two properties! But I am not efficient enough in swift to tell you how subclassing works and type the code for it in swift :)!

Comment: I didn't think to do a `subclass`. doi! I'll give it a try later and let you know if it  solves my issue. I'm definitely still interested in knowing why my code above only works when the `UITextFields` are on the sceen

Comment: It may be because when you're scroll fast and when you press the textField, owing to the re-use of the cells, the cell might not be properly setup by the time you tap it. Of course i'm just spitballing, maybe someone else can give the reason behind it :D